# UK car short term insurance of a non-UK car

Tags: uk, automobiles, insurance

I want to borrow a car of a friend in the UK on a regular, but only daily basis for traveling. I searched the internet for possible short term insurances. The car is registered in a EU country (Germany) and it is insured already. I want to extend the insurance for all damages caused.

For short term insurance companies I found I need a **registration number** of the car to apply. The car is not registered here (since only occasionally around).

Does anybody have an idea how I can borrow the car and being insured against self-caused damages? Is there maybe some platform somewhere the guy can register and I borrow over that portal, to circumvent the lack of insurances?

Comment: Not sure I follow. If the car is registered in Germany, to a German resident and spends most of the year in Germany, you will probably need German insurance.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about travel in the sense intended by this site. From the way your question is phrased, it sounds like you're living in the UK and wanting to drive a car in the UK. The only difference from anyone else wanting to borrow a friend's car in the UK is that the car in question isn't normally in the UK.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am living in the UK and I want to explore/travel the island by car. I guess that short term borrowing is typical thing for travellers, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez the car has a German insurance, but the person is using it for commuting to Britain sometimes (thinks are different compared to UK insurances). I would have the option to borrow it for traveling.

Comment: You should add that information to the question. I think you have a higher chance of getting a relevant answer in expats SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you usually insure the car in the place where it is registered. If you plan to use the car for more than 6 months in the UK then you should register it there. In your particular case the easiest option would be to extend the German insurance to a comprehensive level for the whole EU (if possible), or find another temporary insurance in Germany.